# C# - Is there a way to determine which variable threw null reference exception?

Tags: c#, nullreferenceexception

Would like my logs to indicate which variable threw a null reference exception.

I don't want to manually check every line of code for null values.

Comment: Not which particular variable - but the stack trace should show you which line of code was involved. If that doesn't narrow it down much, consider doing less per statement :)

Comment: "I don't want to manually check every line of code for null values." Then you'll continue to write buggy programs. If a function accepts a parameter that can be null, and your program will crash if null is passed, then you either error check the value or you deal with the exceptions. If you call a function that can return null and you don't check for and report null in your code, then you're going to get those exceptions.

Comment: If you don't like the code to be cluttered use something like an AOP framework (http://www.postsharp.net/blog/post/Validating-parameters-field-and-properties-in-PostSharp-3). To formalize things you can opt for code contracts http://devjourney.com/blog/2014/02/12/code-contracts-part-1-introduction/ but first convince yourself that guarding/defensive programming is a fundamental part of the job.

Answer (score 1):

Actually you do want to employ a very defensive style of coding. It will save you from many issues like this. Yes it may feel boring etc, but on the other hand nulls can happen whenever. If you don't check for them then your application will keep crashing.

It is good to employ the same tactic when you write unit tests. You are supposed to test edge cases and among those edge cases there will be those where you pass nulls or empty strings and make sure your code can deal with that.